# Unknown voltage in IR pulse sensor circuit

Tags: voltage, infrared

I've build a simple circuit based on the sketch from here: http://makezine.com/projects/ir-pulse-sensor/

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f05d2s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, after connecting everything I have strange readings on output. It is all the time value around 60mV. I've been thinking that maybe this is the IR from sun light, but after covering receiving diode with aluminium foil which is meant to block IR light it is still around 60mv on output.

On the attached circuit I've marked places where I measured voltage and the outcome values. Can someone please tell me where can be mistake?

Comment: What sort of value or signal would you expect at these two nodes? How do you measure it? Does the circuit work as intende? BTW a schemetic as referenced by "Schematic with symbolic op-amp representation" is much clearer than the one you included with the LM324 drawn as a single box.

Comment: @jippie Which two nodes? Well, circuit isn't working as intended, because the value of voltage is constant no matter what I will do with IR reciver diode (cover it/uncover and so on.

Comment: The two nodes that you pointed at with the arrows in the previous version. What do you use to measure the voltage? Have you tried to light the IR-diode with a known good IR remote control, eg. from your television?

Comment: @jippie I'v tested with IR remote control . The value is still this same (470mV). Measurement is done quite simply - I am just attaching extra wire in marked place and using digital multimetr I check voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious problem you have is that you didn't copy the circuit correctly. You need a 1k resistor from the - input of the second op amp to ground.

Comment: Well, you are right. But my mistake was because I've been looking at the second sketch (image) with LM324 as an IC. There it isn't mentioned. This is why I don't have it here.

Comment: Without that resistor, the second stage has a gain of 1. With it, the pulse gain is 470 (or 471 if you're using 0.1% resistors). This may make a difference.

Comment: You are right. I've added resistor and now the values make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yuck,  That's a mess of a schematic.  But for a start the photodiode (PD) D2 is put in backwards.  Right now it's always forward biased.. so you get ~0.5V there, and no response for the light.
Flip it around and you'll get V(PD) = 5V- I(PD) * 39 k ohm.  (I'd typically put the resistor R4 to ground, then you have zero signal with no light.)

Comment: You are right - schematic isn't the most beautiful. About your advice, it was very helpfull - now I have around 4,5V on first node (the place where it was 470mV). On the second node I have around 10mV so nothing has changed there.

Comment: @sebap123, of course it's still ~10mV at the second node.  You are AC coupling the signal.  Your first job is to understand how your circuit works.  (The second opamp looks weird, and I'd like a load on the output transistor.)

Answer (score 1):

C1 and C3 block any DC component of the signal.  That is, a steady IR light level will change the voltage at the junction of R4 and D2 (where the schematic shows 470 mV), but will have no effect on the voltages at any point to the right of C3.

The circuit is intended to detect pulsed IR light, as you would get from an IR remote coontrol.  A DVM will probably not respond quickly enough to indicate the presence of such pulses - you would need an oscilliscope to see the recovered pulses.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. So all in all the George Herold answer isn't correct in my case? Am I correct?

Comment: George Herold's answer may also be applicable - I don't thinnk I've ever used photodiodes, so am not qualified to comment on the required polarity.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple design problems with the circuit

1) There is no DC feedback from the output of OA1 to it's negative input.  After a few seconds it will saturate and stop working.

2) The output circuit is incorrect.  Without a resistor to ground the output will not be able to bring the output low.  I suspect the only reason the originator was able to see the signal on a scope is because of the input resistance of the oscilloscope.  Even with the resistor in place the transistor does not do amplify the signal useful and the circuit would work better if Q2 and R2 are removed and the output of OA2 connected directly to the output.

3) The photodiode polarity and missing resistor as indicated by the other responders.

OA1 does nothing useful (as well as stopping it working) and would best be removed.  Connecting the photodiode directly to the positive end of C1 may allow it to work.